# Coding with Sublime Text - having trouble with filepath's in css

Tags: css, image, filepath

So I code in Sublime Text 2 combining HTML, CSS, and jQuery to make web designs.

For some reason, when I am trying to specify a location of a file, say `Pic01.jpg` in the folder `images`, you would suspect typing in `/images/Pic01.jpg` should be enough to tell the browser where the picture is located.

But this is not the case. I find myself needing to specify the exact location of the file before the browser will render it. Like; `User/Desktop/siteOne/images/Pic01.jpg`

This path system is very inconvenient, as I would like to say - export my sites to different computers, but now the code is bound to that specific location on that specific computer.

How can I set it up to make `/images/Pic01.jpg` sufficient coding for the browser (or Sublime?) to understand what needs to be rendered?

Comment: Are you running your website through a web server (MAMP or LAMP) or just opening the HTML file?

Comment: How are you running the site, locally via MAMP/LAMP? Or direct HTML file? If for MAMP/LAMP, you could tell the browser how far back in the directory to go with either ./ or ../ to find the file rather than specifying the exact path which will change once hosted.

Comment: Im just opening the html file, is it better to use mamp standardly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prepending the path by `/` means that it will start it search at the root, which can change depending on your server configuration.

With WAMP/MAMP, I have to prepend my URLs by `/` and then the name of the folder they are in, if they are not at the absolute root of the server. It depends on your setup.

If you want paths that will work regardless of the server root, it's best to use a relative path or use a constant that can easily be changed depending on the configuration.

Example :

```
define("PATH", "/"); 
<a href="<?php echo PATH; ?>directory/myFile">Link that always work</a>
```

You will only have one line to change to make your paths work all the time with a different configuration - relative paths can be tricky to deal with when working in deep sub-folders.

Furthermore, if you want to see where it's actually looking for the file, open the Console in your web browser of choice, they should display the error (404 most likely) and the path it's looking at.

Comment: Thanks foe your detailed awnser, ive been bugges by this issue for a while now. U think i will start using mamp to simulate a server, and see if that works better! Cant upvote your comment due to my points, but you sure helped me out!